# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (\int _a^b|f(x)|^ndx)^\frac 1n=\max\limits_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)|$

Tags: calculus

**Question**:

Evaluate $$\lim _{n \to \infty} (\int _a^b|f(x)|^ndx)^\frac 1n=\max_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)|$$

**Thoughts**:

I thought I'd prove that the limit of $\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ (if I define the sequence as the given integral) is equal to the requested maximum and then that would say something about the limit of the n'th root given here, but that direction didn't turn out very well... Would love some hints first :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $M = \max |f|$, then take $\epsilon > 0$ and $A = \{x \in R : f(x) > M - \epsilon\}$. Also, by $l(A) \in [0,b-a]$ we mean measure of the set $A$.
We can make the following estimation:

$$\sqrt[n]{l(A)} (M-\epsilon) = \sqrt[n]{\int_a^b (M-\epsilon)^n 1_A (x) \, dx} \le \sqrt[n]{\int_a^b |f| dx} \le \sqrt[n]{\int_a^b M \, dx} = \sqrt[n]{b-a} \cdot M$$
Take the limit $\epsilon \to 0$, $n \to +\infty$ and you're done.

Comment: Nice and very elegant!